# FFMpeg adding silence: struggling to use -i anullsrc option

Tags: ffmpeg

I am just trying to add a silent audio track to a video file using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -i anullsrc -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest test.mkv
```

I have ffmpeg precompiled release for windows 64bit (20170208)

Whenever I run I get this error:

```
anullsrc: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate; the linked question did not answer my question, which is about "No such file or directory", and the answer below solved my issue.

Answer (score 32):

I had to specify the `lavfi` filter as well and put it *before* `-i anullsrc`:

```
-f lavfi
```

For a complete commandline:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest test.mkv
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the only answer that actually solved this specific problem. Any idea why it works?

Comment: @Matt Replying to an old question, but you have to tell `ffmpeg` which input is a filter by using the format option (`-f`) with value `lavfi` (libavfilter virtual input device). Omitting `-f` makes `ffmpeg` assume `anullsrc` is a file name.

Comment: And if the FFmpeg process goes forever use: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc=cl=mono dummy.m4a` to generate a dummy silent file.
https://superuser.com/questions/1260831/ffmpeg-conversion-runs-forever

Comment: Thank you! Been looking everywhere for this.