# ffmpeg: Generate empty audio and video (working for video)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate a black video with FFMPEG. I have accomplished this with the following:

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Unfortunately this video doesn't have any audio tracks. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147512/ffmpeg-adding-silence-struggling-to-use-i-anullsrc-option), I have tried to insert **-i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100**:

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Unfortunately this gives the error:

> anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100: No such file or
> directory

How can I modify my initial script to generate a video with empty audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anullsrc` is also a source filter so it too needs `-f lavfi` before it.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 5 -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080 -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`